# Created a linked list, but how to delete 'all' the nodes in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, delete-operator

I wrote the following code for creating linked list. So, I wanted  to know how to delete all the nodes of the linked list. And I also wanted to know the way I *created the nodes and inserted elements* into them was the right way.

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    node *next;
};
int main()
{
    node *head, *temp;
    cout << "enter no of elements" << endl;
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    //=============Creating Nodes And Inserting Elements===========//
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter the element in " << i << "th node" << endl;
        if(i == 0)
        {
            temp = new node(); 
            cin >> temp->val; 
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=new node();
            temp=temp->next;
            cin >> temp->val;
        }
    }
    temp->next=NULL;

    //===================Deleting all the nodes=================//


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Walk the list and `delete` the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a linked list in several ways, I will show you a way of them:

The structure:

```
struct linkedList {
    int data;         // store data
    linkedList *next; // store a pointer to the next node
} *head; // "head" is a pointer points to the first node
```

The following function is a simple way to create a new node:

```
void InsertNode(int data){
    linkedList *node = new linkedList;
    node->data = data;
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}
```

And when you want to delete all nodes that in the linked list:

```
void deleteAllNodes(){
    linkedList *temp = head, *next;
    while(temp != NULL){
        next = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = next;
    }
    delete head;
    head = NULL;
}
```

If there is something unclear comment.

Comment: does `delete temp;` and `free(temp)` works the same? Because I had seen the **new** creates a free memory block and **malloc** creates a heap memory

Comment: Short answer: malloc -> free , new -> delete. (The two ways create a memory in the heap).

Answer (score 1):

You `delete` all nodes by walking through the list:

```
node *temptemp;      // tempory variable to store
                     // the next list nodes address
for (temp = head;    // begin at the head of the list
     temp;           // as long as temp != NULL
     temp = temptemp // the temp->next we stored in the loops body
) {
    temptemp = temp->next;  // remember temp->next cause
    delete temp;            // next is gone now.
}
```

Comment: Can you explain briefly the `for (temp = head; temp; temp = temptemp)`

Comment: @ Done in my answer. HTH.

Comment: [link](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AmAHV2fOkXzXgxoITRSKY_ZLoOHz) does this work @swordfish

Comment: `temp = temp2;` is missing as the last line of the `else`-block. Next time please update your question instead of spamming the same question as comment to each answer.

Answer (score 1):

use destructor

```
struct node
{
    ~node()
    {
        if (NULL != next)
        {
            delete next;
        }
    }

    int val;
    node *next = NULL; //initialize with NULL
};
```

now from your main delete head node

```
int main()
{
    ...
    delete head;
    ...
}
```

Comment: does the destructor delete all the nodes or only one node?

Comment: destructor will not delete any nodes, its an event/notification when we try to delete an object. In the example we deleted head from main() function and now node::destructor will get the notification, when we receive the notification we are trying to delete next pointer, which will again call its destructor finally it will delete all the nodes. Learn more about destructors it will be really interesting :).

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious question is why are you creating your own list instead of using something from the STL like `std::list`? The way you are coding is more like C than C++. Methods to add, remove, etc nodes should be member functions of the node structure. For example:

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    node *next;

    explicit node(int val = 0) : val{val}, next{nullptr} {}

    void add_node(node *nodep) {
        node *tail = this;
        while (tail->next != nullptr)
            tail = tail->next;
        tail->next = nodep;
    }

    ~node() {
        delete next;
    }
};
```

But using a container from the STL is really the best.